# Automatically turn on turned off computer

Tags: windows

I've surfed several sites where it is written how to turn on computer from the only sleeping mode, but nowhere how to turn on already turned off computer. Is there no way to turn on my (turned off) computer in the morning for running `.bat` file and waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **WOL** (Wake On LAN).

The first step is to enable the option in your computer **BIOS**. The rest of the procedure will depend on your operating system.

Have a look here: [What Is Wake-on-LAN, and How Do I Enable It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can turn off you computer with a .bat file
put in your bat file the following command:

shutdown /s

Comment: I want to turn it on